# C Array creating Trojan?

Tags: c, arrays, codeblocks, trojan

I recently stared learning C. everything was fine but suddenly when today I was trying the 2d array with CodeBlocks Windows Defender constantly showing that my compiled file is a "Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.C!cl" . What to do? Any help please

I didn't install anything except MinGW & Latest CodeBlocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int row,col,a[5][3]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    for(row=0; row<5; row++)
    {
        for(col=0; col<3; col++)
            printf("%d ", a[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: Make sure your AV software is up to date. Run it on your compiler and supporting tools. In case of doubt, reinstall your o/s, taking care not to reinstall the virus if you recover material from backups.  — Do you run into problems still if you change the array size, name, content, etc? Do you only get the problem with a 2D array (1D?  3D?). It's unlikely that MS Windows Defender would misidentify such a simple program as a trojan — it's more likely there's infected software on the system that makes the program into a trojan and the alert is valid. Where did you get CodeBlocks and MinGW from?

Comment: Submit the resulting executable to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) and see whether the other virus engines flag it as a valid trojan.